# Simple function plotting question

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a graph to show that its minimum occurs at $a = \frac{n}{2}$. Here is the function: $f(a) =  \frac{2a^2 -2an+n^2 - n}{2}$. It's derivative is 
$g(a) = 2a - n$.

Why does

```
f [a_, n_] := 2 a - n

Plot[f[a, n], {n, -1, 1}]
```

Not work as I intend it to?

Comment: Because your function has no value for $a$, for one reason.  And you should not have a blank after `f` for another.

Comment: Also, if you are plotting a function of two variables (a surface), you need to use `Plot3D`

Comment: Plot3D[{f[a, n], 0}, {n,-1,1}, {a,-1,1}] and then place your cursor inside that plot and drag it around until you are looking directly down on the top of the plot. That will show you one color half-sheet representing your g and another color half sheet showing where the intersection with zero is. From that you should be able to see how and where g[a]==zero.

Answer (score 3):

```
f[a_, n_] = (2 a^2 - 2 a*n - n)/2;
```

To minimize `f` with respect to `a`

```
Minimize[f[a, n], a] // Simplify

(*  {(-(1/4))*n*(2 + n), {a -> n/2}}  *)
```

Alternatively, set the first partial derivative to zero and the second partial derivative to be positive

```
Solve[
  {D[f[a, n], a] == 0, D[f[a, n], {a, 2}] > 0}, a][[1]]

(*  {a -> n/2}  *)
```

Graphically,

```
Show[
 Plot3D[f[a, n], {a, -4, 4}, {n, -8, 8},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {a, n, f})],
 ParametricPlot3D[
  {n/2, n, f[n/2, n]}, {n, -8, 8},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Using [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html)

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[f[a, n], {a, -4, 4},
  Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {a, f}),
  PlotRange -> {-22, 12},
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
    Point[{n/2, f[n/2, n]}], Dashed,
    Line[{{n/2, -22}, {n/2, 12}}]}],
 {{n, 0}, -8, 8, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]